# Online Github Readme Writer

Tags: svn, github

Is there an online gihub readme writer? I don't know Markdown syntax and am not interested to learn this at all if there is a tool where I can write text, format it and download md file.

Have you ever come across any?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Mac, you could try **[Byword](http://bywordapp.com/)**.

However, as explained in "[Why doesn't the site use a rich text editor?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/28355/6309)" (for Stack Overflow, but equally applicable for GitHub):

> WYSIWYG RTE editors are generally bad at structuring the underlying data, making it very difficult to analyze/restructure the contents.
> [...] markup usually conveys structure. WYSIWYG RTE editors usually conveys optical style.

---

As mention by the [OP Umair Ashraf](https://stackoverflow.com/users/355507/umair-ashraf) in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9059423/online-github-readme-writer/9060404#comment11380254_9060404), he is not so much after an external wysiwig editor, but after an embeded JavaScript editor like the one used for Stack Overflow ([reversed from an existing one in 2008](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/12/reverse-engineering-the-wmd-editor/), with an [initial repo here](https://github.com/derobins/wmd)).
One of the most advance fork of that original project is [jquery-markedit](https://github.com/tstone/jquery-markedit/wiki).

A good example (not exactly a Markdown editor though, but a Mardown parser), mentioned by [the OP Umair Ashraf](https://stackoverflow.com/users/355507/umair-ashraf) in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9059423/online-github-readme-writer/9060404#comment11406648_9060404) is the project [**documentup**](http://documentup.com/):

> Instantly beautify your Github repositories' `README.md` with DocumentUp.
> This site has been generated with it.

> Essentially, it parses your `readme`'s markdown into a clean and simple documentation website.
> Made especially for your **`gh-pages`** branch, all you need is a single `index.html` file that includes the DocumentUp script (Some configuration required).

Comment: I particularly didn't mean WYSIWYG editor but any simple html <textarea> based editor that has buttons on top to let me format and style the readme. Something like SO question editor.

Comment: @UmairAshraf good point. I don't know about a JavaScript editor for GitHub markdown.

Comment: So what do you say should I learn markdown first and write similar editor for the community?

Comment: @Umair: learing Mardown isn't a waste of time, considering it is used on other sites as well. Writing an editor is possible, but you might want to check first with GitHub: would they consider adding a "Request for Enhancement" for the edition of their page? If not, your editor would remain unused.

Comment: Well who cares if github doesn't add this. It can be for those who don't want to learn Markdown. And above all, I don't think it would take more than 3-4 hours of mine to write it.

Comment: @UmairAshraf interesting. You should publish your cide for that editor in a... GitHub project ;)

Comment: @UmairAshraf: I have edited my answer to include what you were actually after, and also to point out the existing sources for Javascript Markdown editors.

Comment: @UmairAshraf: interesting example of a Markdown *parser* (not exactly an editor). I have updated my answer to include it though.

Comment: They say "Instantly beautify your Github repositories' README.md with DocumentUp. This site has been generated with it.". That's what I was looking for.

Comment: @UmairAshraf: excellent, then. That's why I have added it to the answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

The [online markup editor](http://homepage.univie.ac.at/werner.robitza/markdown/) might be interesting.